# Is it possible to place an iframe inside a swf file?

Tags: html, flash

I tried to search around but i didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like...

http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

or

http://sourceforge.net/projects/as3htmlparser/

---

I haven't tried this but...

https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to insert iFrame inside a Flex application.

https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe